# How can I use the ProgressBar with Async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Controlling the progress bar with the backgroundworker made my project difficult after a certain place. In this case, I decided to move on async structure, I built the architecture on the async structure. But this time I did not know how to control the progress bar under the async structure.

```
 private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 1;
        int value = 1;
        await ProgressBarControl(value);
        await Convert();

    }
    public Task ProgressBarControl(int e)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = percent;
            });
        }); 
    }
```

But it is not working. I used backgroundworker. I was asking this question. But you guys suggested to me backgroundworker. But backgroundworker, after a while have a error and system is not answered to me?

Comment: The `Progress` class should be created *outside* the background method. The background method should only use the `IProgress<T>` interface and its `Report` method

Comment: BTW there's no useful asynchronous code in the question. Just a call to `Task.Run` that doesn't really try to do something in the background. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The progress bar will progress depending on the processing time. I was advised to do this with the backgroundworker, but I had problems. I also learned that I can run task and async on the suggestion but I don't know how to proceed @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: BGW *was* used to run jobs in the background, the same way `Task.Run` does since 2012. It's *not* needed to update the UI. In any case you aren't using it here at all. I already posted an answer showing the correct code and a link to a tutorial that shows how progress and cancellation works with async operations

Comment: Async methods are expected to have names with an `Async` suffix. Your `ProgressBarControl` method doesn't follow this convention. Actually it doesn't follow the [guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-methods) of naming methods in general: *method names be verbs or verb phrases*. You may think that it's not important, but it actually is. Unconventional names create confusion, and coding is already a confusing business. Communicating the intention of your code with proper naming reduces bugs and increases maintainability.

Comment: I am learning this method, How can ı do this?I  did just what ı saw for about this subject? I am learning new, actually @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 2):

The question is unlcear. BackgroundWorker is osbsolete since 2012 anyway.

If you want to report progress from *any* background thread, not just threads created with `Task.Run`, create a `Progress<T>` in the UI thread and pass it only as an `IProgress<T>` to the background thread or task, eg :

```
private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var progress = new Progress<int>(percent => {
        progressBar1.Value = percent;
    });

    progressBar1.Value = 1;
    int value = 100;
    await DoSomeWork(value, progress);
}

public Task DoSomeWork(int iterations, IProgress<int> progress) {
    for(int i=0; i < iterations; i++) {
        await Task.Run(() => {
           DoSomethingReallySlow(i);
           progress.Report(i * 100 / iterations));
        });
    }
}
```

Check [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) for an example of both progress reporting and cancellation

Comment: DoSomethingReallySlow() is what I mean inside, so let me write my functional instead of convert. But I understand that a function that increases i @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: And ı have a error "DoSomeWork (int,Iprogress<int>) not all code paths return a value,                                                      error 2 : the await operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the  async modifier and changing its return type to ' Task<Task>'                                                                         error  3  about for DoSomethingRealyShow() method @PanagiotisKanavos